# How can I use multithreading to speed up my SHA-1 cracker?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, processing

I've been messing around with encryption and hashing lately and I was trying to make something to brute force SHA-1 just using text. After writing the basic code and confirming that it works I wanted to try to make it more efficient, however I couldn't find much which needed to be made more efficient. So, I did what I thought was the smart thing to do: add threads.

Only problem is, I can't find a good way to implement them, if there is one. I tried one implementation, and despite using almost 3x as much CPU power, it took 10x as long as the single threaded version.

So, if you'd be so kind as to take a look and give me some tips I'd greatly appreciate them.

**Single threaded**

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
public int tim1;

void setup(){ //This is the main code block.
  String input = "9e05e6832caffca519722b608570b8ff4935b94d"; //SHA-1 Hexadecimal Hash to be cracked
  String chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789._!"; //Alphabet to use
  int num = 7; //Maximum number of letters to try

  tim1=millis(); //Starting timer
  println(crack(input,chars,num)); //Cracking the input and outputting the result
  println((millis()-tim1)/(float)1000); //Printing how long it took to crack.
}

//This function will take as input, a SHA-1 hash, an alphabet, and a maximum number of characters to test.
//It will either output the original string which converts to the hash, or "Unable to crack" if the given parameters do not lead to it.
String crack(String input, String chars, int num){ 
  byte[] inp = hexStringToByteArray(input); //Converting the input to a byte array.
  String output;

  for(int i = 1; i<=num;i++){ //Bruteforce all passwords of length i, where i = 1 through num
    output = bforce("",chars,i,inp); 
    if(output!=null){ //If the brute force algorithm outputs anything other than null, then the output is the cracked hash.
      return output;
    }
  }
  //If it returns null every time then either we didn't try enough characters, or it contained characters outside of our alphabet.
  return "Unable to crack";
}

//This function will take as input, an intermediate string, an alphabet, a number of characters, and a sha-1 byte array to test against.
//It will test every combination of characters from the alphabet that can be added to the end intermediate string
//It only tests for a given length of num.
//To use the function on its own, you should simply provide an empty intermediate string.
//The function will either output null if it couldn't find the input that leads to the hash, or it will output the string that leads to the hash.
String bforce(String inter, String chars, int num,byte[] inp){
//This function will do pretty much all of the computations.
  try{ //Try to run this code
    String test; //String to be tested.

    if(num-inter.length()==1){ //If the intermediate string contains all but one character, then run this code.
      for(int i=0;i<chars.length();i++){ //For every character in the given alphabet
        test=inter+chars.charAt(i); //Set the test string to the intermediate string + that character
        if(bEquals(MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").digest(test.getBytes()),inp)){ //Then convert that string into a SHA-1 Hash and see if it's equal to the input
          return test; //If it is, then stop the code and return it.
        } //Otherwise, keep going.
      }

    } else { //Otherwise, run this code.
      for(int i=0;i<chars.length();i++){//For every character in the given alphabet
        test=bforce(inter+chars.charAt(i),chars,num,inp);//Try every combination of letters after the intermediate string + that character
        if(test!=null){//If one of their hashes is equal to the input byte array
          return test; //Then stop the code and return it
        } // Otherwise, keep going.
      }
    }
    return null; //If the code is still running at this point, it means that we've tried every possibility.
  } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { //If the code gives this specific type of error.
    throw new RuntimeException(e); //Then stop the code and print the error.
  }
}

//This function simply takes two byte arrays and outputs true if they're equal, or false if they're not.
boolean bEquals(byte[] x,byte[] y){
  if(x.length!=y.length){ //If the lengths of the arrays aren't equal,
    return false; //Then the arrays can't be equal, so return false and stop here.
  } else { //Otherwise,
    for(int i = 0;i<x.length;i++){//For every element in the first array
      if(x[i]!=y[i]){//If it's not equal to the corresponding element in the second array,
        return false;//Then return false and stop here.
      }//Otherwise, keep going.
    }
    return true;//If the code is still running here, then it means that the arrays are equal, so return true.
  }
}
//This function is not mine. I borrowed it off the internet, it simply takes a hexadecimal number in the form of a string, and converts it to a binary number in the form of a Byte array.
byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                             + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

**Multi-threaded**

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
public int tim1;
//Variables which will be used to pass data between threads
Thread thrd1;
Thread thrd2;
Thread thrd3;
MessageDigest msgdig1;
MessageDigest msgdig2;
MessageDigest msgdig3;
public int third1num1;
public int third2num1;
public int third3num1;
public int third1num2;
public int third2num2;
public int third3num2;
public String thread1output = null;
public String thread2output = null;
public String thread3output = null;
public String intermediate1;
public String intermediate2;
public String intermediate3;
public String alphabet1;
public String alphabet2;
public String alphabet3;
public byte[] inpt1;
public byte[] inpt2;
public byte[] inpt3;

void setup(){ //This is the main code block.
  String input = "9e05e6832caffca519722b608570b8ff4935b94d"; //SHA-1 Hexadecimal Hash to be cracked
  String chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789._!"; //Alphabet to use
  int num = 5; //Maximum number of letters to try

  tim1=millis(); //Starting timer
  println(crack(input,chars,num)); //Cracking the input and outputting the result
  println((millis()-tim1)/(float)1000); //Printing how long it took to crack.
}

//This function will take as input, a SHA-1 hash, an alphabet, and a maximum number of characters to test.
//It will either output the original string which converts to the hash, or "Unable to crack" if the given paramaters do not lead to it.
String crack(String input, String chars, int num){ 
  byte[] inp = hexStringToByteArray(input); //Converting the input to a byte array.
  String output;

  for(int i = 1; i<=num;i++){ //Bruteforce all passwords of length i, where i = 1 through num
    output = bforce("",chars,i,inp); 
    if(output!=null){ //If the brute force algorithm outputs anything other than null, then the output is the cracked hash.
      return output;
    }
  }
  //If it returns null every time then either we didn't try enough characters, or it contained characters outside of our alphabet.
  return "Unable to crack";
}

//This function will take as input, an intermediate string, an alphabet, a number of characters, and a sha-1 byte array to test against.
//It will test every combination of characters from the alphabet that can be added to the end intermediate string
//It only tests for a given length of num.
//To use the function on its own, you should simply provide an empty intermediate string.
//The function will either output null if it couldn't find the input that leads to the hash, or it will output the string that leads to the hash.
String bforce(String inter, String chars, int num,byte[] inp){
//This function will do pretty much all of the computations.
  if(inter.equals("aaaa")){println("aaaa");}
  String test; //String to be tested.
  if(inter.equals("")){
    //Setting up the threads
    thrd1 = new Thread(new thread1());
    thrd2 = new Thread(new thread2());
    thrd3 = new Thread(new thread3());
    //Setting up Message digesters for threads
    try{
      msgdig1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
      msgdig2 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
      msgdig3 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    //Dividing the alphabet into thirds for the threads to use.
    println("mhm");
    alphabet1 = chars;
    alphabet2 = chars;
    alphabet3 = chars;
    third3num1 = chars.length();
    third1num1 = third3num1/3;
    third2num1 = third1num1*2;
    third1num2 = third1num1;
    third2num2 = third2num1;
    third3num2 = third3num1;
    //Setting the input for the threads to use
    inpt3 = inp; 
    inpt2 = inp; 
    inpt1 = inp; 
  }
  if(num-inter.length()==1){ //If the intermediate string contains all but one character, then run this code.
    //Provide the intermediate for the threads to use
    intermediate1=inter;
    intermediate2=inter;
    intermediate3=inter;
    //Set up the threads
    thrd1 = new Thread(new thread1());
    thrd2 = new Thread(new thread2());
    thrd3 = new Thread(new thread3());
    //Run the threads
    try{
      thrd1.start();
      thrd2.start();
      thrd3.start();
    } catch(Exception e){
      println(thrd1.getState());
      println(thrd2.getState());
      println(thrd3.getState());
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    //Wait for the other threads to finish
    try{
      thrd1.join();
      thrd2.join();
      thrd3.join();
    } catch(Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    if(thread1output!=null){ //If any of the threads found matching strings, then return them and stop the code.
      return thread1output;
    } else if (thread2output!=null){
      return thread2output;
    } else if (thread3output!=null){
      return thread3output;
    }
    return null; //Otherwise, return null and stop the code.
  } else { //Otherwise, run this code.
    for(int i=0;i<chars.length();i++){//For every character in the given alphabet
      test=bforce(inter+chars.charAt(i),chars,num,inp);//Try every combination of letters after the intermediate string + that character
      if(test!=null){//If one of their hashes is equal to the input byte array
        return test; //Then stop the code and return it
      } // Otherwise, keep going.
    }
  }
  return null; //If the code is still running at this point, it means that we've tried every possibility.
}
//These threads help spread the workload out across the CPU threads
public class thread1 implements Runnable {
  public void run(){ //When this thread is started, run this code.
    try { //Try to run this code
      for(int i=0;i<third1num1;i++){//For every character in the first third of the alphabet
        String test1=intermediate1+alphabet1.charAt(i);//Set the test string to the intermediate string + that character
        if(bEquals(msgdig1.digest(test1.getBytes()),inpt1)){//Then convert that string into a SHA-1 Hash and see if it's equal to the input
          thread1output=test1;//If it is, then stop the code and return it.
          return;
        } // Otherwise, keep going.
      }
      thread1output=null;//If none of the test strings' hashes are equivalent to the input, then set our output to null
      return;
    } catch (Exception e) { //If there's an error,
      throw new RuntimeException(e); //Stop everything and print it.
    }
  }
}
public class thread2 implements Runnable {
  public void run(){ //When this thread is started, run this code.
    try { //Try to run this code
      for(int i=third1num2;i<third2num1;i++){//For every character in the second third of the alphabet
        String test2=intermediate2+alphabet2.charAt(i);//Set the test string to the intermediate string + that character
        if(bEquals(msgdig2.digest(test2.getBytes()),inpt2)){//Then convert that string into a SHA-1 Hash and see if it's equal to the input
          thread2output=test2;//If it is, then stop the code and return it.
          return;
        } // Otherwise, keep going.
      }
      thread2output=null;//If none of the test strings' hashes are equivalent to the input, then set our output to null
      return;
    } catch (Exception e) { //If there's an error,
      throw new RuntimeException(e); //Stop everything and print it.
    }
  }
}
public class thread3 implements Runnable {
  public void run(){ //When this thread is started, run this code.
    try { //Try to run this code
      for(int i=third2num2;i<third3num1;i++){//For every character in the final third of the alphabet
        String test3=intermediate3+alphabet3.charAt(i);//Set the test string to the intermediate string + that character
        if(bEquals(msgdig3.digest(test3.getBytes()),inpt3)){//Then convert that string into a SHA-1 Hash and see if it's equal to the input
          thread3output=test3;//If it is, then stop the code and return it.
          return;
        } // Otherwise, keep going.
      }
      thread3output=null;//If none of the test strings' hashes are equivalent to the input, then set our output to null
      return;
    } catch (Exception e) { //If there's an error,
      throw new RuntimeException(e); //Stop everything and print it.
    }
  }
}
//This function simply takes two byte arrays and outputs true if they're equal, or false if they're not.
boolean bEquals(byte[] x,byte[] y){
  if(x.length!=y.length){ //If the lengths of the arrays aren't equal,
    return false; //Then the arrays can't be equal, so return false and stop here.
  } else { //Otherwise,
    for(int i = 0;i<x.length;i++){//For every element in the first array
      if(x[i]!=y[i]){//If it's not equal to the corresponding element in the second array,
        return false;//Then return false and stop here.
      }//Otherwise, keep going.
    }
    return true;//If the code is still running here, then it means that the arrays are equal, so return true.
  }
}
//This function is not mine. I borrowed it off the internet, it simply takes a hexadecimal number in the form of a string, and converts it to a binary number in the form of a Byte array.
byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                             + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: I'm looking closely, but so far I haven't been able to spot any difference between the two different versions of the code. Which methods/lines are actually different in the second version?

Comment: @Bobulous So sorry about that! I can be a null brain sometimes. I guess I copy pasted the same thing twice, but anyways, I fixed the post now.

Comment: FYI: The way you have structured your program, with a `thread1` class and a nearly identical `thread2` class and a `thread3` class and all those `foo1bar`, `foo2bar`, `foo3bar` variables, _strongly_ suggests that you are very new to programming. IMO, you should get more practice writing single-threaded programs before you try diving in to multi-threading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a computation-heavy task like this, the number of CPU cores directly limits how many tasks can be run in parallel. You get no benefit from having more threads than you have cores.

If you only started new threads in the top level of the recursion, with the code you have I would expect a 3x speedup. The threads don't depend on each other for anything. By starting new threads on the last level of recursion, you are creating thousands of threads. The overhead from creating and coordinating these threads is far greater than the benefit you could get by running things in parallel:

```
String bforce(String inter, String chars, int num,byte[] inp){
  if(inter.equals("")){
    // Start your 3 threads
  } else if(num-inter.length()==1){
    // DON'T start threads - use the existing logic you had
  } else { //Otherwise, run this code.
    // Recursive case
  }
}
```

That will however limit you to using 3 CPU cores, and you are still managing threads manually which is not easy. It would be much better to use the a high level API.

For example, you could create a thread pool that has the same number of threads as you have CPU cores, and then create tasks for the thread pool to run in parallel. This would ensure you use all available CPU resources, with minimal overhead.

```
// global scope
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

// in "bforce"
if (inter.equals("")) {

    // Create tasks to run in thread pool
    List<Callable<String>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length(); i++) {
        String newInter = chars.substring(i, i + 1);
        tasks.add(() -> bforce(newInter, chars, num, inp));
    }

    // Run all tasks in thread pool and wait for results
    List<Future<String>> futures = threadPool.invokeAll(tasks);

    // Inspect the results
    for (Future<String> future : futures) {
        String result = future.get();
        // not sure what you want to do with this result...
    }
}
```